# Using the Freeze functionality as a user in the BNB contract

Tags: tokens, metamask, contract-invocation, binance

In the [BNB contract](https://vscode.blockscan.com/ethereum/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52) there is the Freeze and UnFreeze functionality.
As I have understood, this doesn't allow Binance to freeze users’ balances. Instead, it allows any user to freeze and unfreeze their own funds.

My question is: How could I, as a user, interact with the smart contract in order to freeze/lock BNB tokens in my wallet (e.g. Metamask).

View also: https://medium.com/@danielque/bnb-token-freeze-functionality-ca37d5630bda

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about about BNB provides with the UI, but I can tell you the raw method.

You can visit etherscan https://etherscan.io/address/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52#writeContract

Here you will see the contract tab, click on that, and below that you'll notice `write contract`, click on that and you'll see the freeze function, enter the amount and call the function. Make sure to enter the amount with 18 leading zeros.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that was possible!